# Default Font Sizes in Foundation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

The [Foundation Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) has different predefined font sizes for [headlines](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/typography.html).

**Are there also predefined font sizes for the body of the page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its `font-size: 1rem;`  for fonts.
check [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/typography)

Comment: Well this is the same page I posted in my link. The question was: Are there also predefined font sizes for the body of the page? Not only one.

Comment: There is only one size for paragraph. If you want to change it you can!
http://cl.ly/image/0e3t1C1Z142N < like this